# Duplicate entry 'vtfszyfxemkrwu52hjyugphb-1' for key 'PRIMARY' when using MySqlSessionStateStore

Tags: mysql, asp.net, session, session-timeout, mysql-connector

I have the same issue that has been asked by DavKa in this post [MySQL Session state provider crashes on expired sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397376/mysql-session-state-provider-crashes-on-expired-sessions).

Basically I am using MySqlSessionStateProvider( the provider from MySQL for session management) for session persistence and it works fine. It stores the session and a stored proc removes expired sessions. I need to redirect to a "Session Expired" page when the user is inactive and session expires which allows the user to log on once again.

Unfortunately when the session expires instead of redirecting to the Session Expired page ( which I have configured in the MasterPage http://aspalliance.com/1621_Implementing_a_Session_Timeout_Page_in_ASPNET.3) it throws an error stating that there is already an entry for the said primary key. Im assuming it is trying to insert the same session into the session store table without the previous one being deleted.

Has anyone else faced this issue and been able to  work around it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S: This is my first SO post so please excuse any noob mistakes.

Comment: If you want help with code, you should publish what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Noich: Thanks for your reply. I am not looking for help with coding. I just need to know if anyone who has implemented MySQL session store has come across the same error and how they handled session timeout without showing the user the YSOD.

Answer (score 1):

This has been a pain in my rear for months.  Coded "around" the problem (i.e. used in-memory sessions) for a while but now, at the point of no return, I've fixed it myself.

[MySQL Session state provider crashes on expired sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397376/mysql-session-state-provider-crashes-on-expired-sessions/20964070#20964070)

Download fix from here, until MySql rolls it in:

https://github.com/xavierjefferson/mysql-web-fixed